# web based data visualization application with back end spark?

Tags: apache-spark, data-visualization, apache-zeppelin, bigdata

I am looking for a data visualization tool, that is open source, and uses apache Spark as the back end.I did some research and  could narrow down to Apache Zeppelin, where I can generate charts/graphs etc  based on tables created in Spark SQL, but here is my problem, there would be non technical users looking at the data visuals, and I don't think they would know how to write SQL etc.So I would like to see if anybody knows a better way/ tool.Something that would let them drag /drop and no coding at all, minimal learning curve .Please advice.

Thanks
Pradeep

Comment: Have you got some SQL-based tool, that you've already used? If yes, then you can run Spark JDBC Server and connect to it via your tool

Answer (score 1):

This might not exactly the answer to fit your needs.

**There are some commercial tools for drag and drop support.**

- Tableau
- Tibco Spotfire
- SAS Visual Analytics

The thing is that a user friendly drag and drop tool is very costly to build.

**If we have a well designed Zeppelin notebook by data engineer with functions like.**

- Load data to spark
- Some paragraph to explore the data with [Dynamic Form](https://zeppelin.apache.org/docs/0.6.1/manual/dynamicform.html)
- Publish result

Then perhaps large amount of use case already can be solved.

**Based on modify code is much easier than write code. Assume we have following code to analyze and plot chart with [spark-highcharts](https://github.com/knockdata/spark-highcharts) in a zeppelin notebook.**

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import com.knockdata.spark.highcharts._
import com.knockdata.spark.highcharts.model._

highcharts(bank
  .series("x" -> "age", "y" -> avg(col("balance")))
  .orderBy(col("age"))).plot()
```

Then we can have a short guidance like

> There are columns `marital`, `job`, `education`... can be used to replace `age`
>
> There are functions `sum`, `min`, `max` ... to replace `avg`

Answer (score 1):

I Strongly suggest you could try this website https://rawgraphs.io;
This online tool really helps me. It based on D3js which is very popular these days. However, the process is super simple, upload your data, choose the style, and drag the attribute. The web would generate svg, png ,and pdf file for you to download.